# Retrieving images using Jquery gallery plugin dynamically

Tags: jquery

How do I dynamically retreieve images using any jquery gallery/slideshow plugins?

I have images that I can retrieve like this..

http://localhost/images.aspx?id=1

http://localhost/images.aspx?id=2

I have already made a REST based service to return an array of those links when I pass the fromdate and todate.

After using Jquery to retrieve those links,I want to load the images.

The samples in most of the demos only talk about statically assigning images.

Please show me a sample on loading the images dynamically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the REST response will be like this

```
http://localhost/images.aspx?id=1
```

---

Your jquery ajax code should be like this

The code after requesting from REST thru ajax will add the path **http://localhost/images.aspx?id=1** to the IMG tag

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#imagepic').attr('src',data);
  }
});
```

Comment: but how do I create the image tags dynamically? In this case,I must have a static img tag named imagepic right? but i need to create the tags also dynamically

Comment: I just made a new post to reply to your query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174763/retrieving-images-using-jquery-gallery-plugin-dynamically/2175242#2175242

Answer (score 0):

To also dynamically create the image tag  dynamically do this, asumming its inside a div tag

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#div1').html("<img src='".data."' id='#imagepic'/>");
  }
});
```